# Target Specific Select in DataGrid Pagination

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I want to change the font size of all numbers (10, 25, and 50 as seen in this screenshot below) inside rows per page select element inside a pagination of a `DataGrid` component.

[image]

I inspected each number and I got `.MuiMenuItem-root` as the selector for each element.

Then I changed the `font-size` and `color` (just to prove that `.MuiMenuItem-root` was the right selector) as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

The result was successful.
When I applied the selector in my code, the `font-size` didn't work (nothing changed).

Here is my code:

CustomDataGrid.js:

```
import { DataGridPro } from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const CustomDataGrid = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    // ROOT
    height: '100%',
    border: 'none',

    ...some code here

    // PAGINATION
    '& .MuiTablePagination-caption': {
      fontSize: 12,
    },
    '& .MuiTablePagination-select': {
      fontSize: 12,
    },
    '& .MuiMenuItem-root': {
      fontSize: 12,
    },
    '& .MuiIconButton-root': {
      padding: 8,
    },
  },
}))(DataGridPro)

export default CustomDataGrid
```

dependencies (in package.json file):

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
"@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",
"@mui/x-data-grid": "^4.0.0",
"@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^4.0.0",
```

So how can I change the `font-size` of all numbers inside the select element inside a pagination of a Data Grid component using `withStyles`?

Comment: I think the reason it doesn't work is because your menu list is using [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). It's not inside the `DataGrid` in the DOM tree so the `font-size` can't be inherited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGrid` has a [`Pagination`](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/#:%7E:text=toolbar%20by%20default.-,Pagination,-elementType) slot to let you override the pagination component and its props. It uses `TablePagination` behind the scene, which [exposes](https://mui.com/api/table-pagination/#:%7E:text=all%20the%20rows.-,SelectProps,-object) the `SelectProps` to let you override the `Select` component. The `Select` itself has a [`MenuProps`](https://mui.com/api/select/#:%7E:text=the%20selected%20value.-,MenuProps,-object) which allows you to override the props of the dropdown overlay. So with all of that, this is what you have to do to target the right component:

```
<DataGrid
  pagination
  {...data}
  componentsProps={{
    pagination: {
      SelectProps: {
        MenuProps: {
          sx: {
            color: "red",
            "& .MuiMenuItem-root": {
              fontSize: 30
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: so I couldn't style the font size of numbers inside the select element in the pagination using ```withStyles```? using ```withStyles```` allows us to use the same component multiple times

Comment: @JabalLogian you can use `withStyles`, the exposed props also have the `className`  so you can change it if you want: `MenuProps: { className: classes.menu }`. See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/69462526-target-specific-selector-data-grid-material-ui-forked-rocwe?file=/demo.tsx) demo.

Comment: hmm I tried to use your answer in my code but still didn't work. I don't know why both of your answers in the codesandbox worked.

Comment: @JabalLogian it works [fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/69462526-target-specific-selector-data-grid-material-ui-forked-rocwe?file=/demo.tsx) with the packages from your question

Comment: sorry for late response, I saw there was no rows per page select component in the newest link you gave to me. I added ```pageSize```, ```onPageSizeChange```, and ```rowsPerPageOptions``` in your latest code but still no rows per page select component shown

Comment: @JabalLogian yeah I struggled with that for a while too, turned out MUI hides the Select when on small screen, try zooming out or increase the width and you'll see it

Comment: you're right, I tried to copy and modify your answer here https://codesandbox.io/s/data-grid-material-ui-c01c8?file=/src/CustomDataGrid.js but it's not working, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: @JabalLogian you forgot to spread the props: [`<CustomDataGrid {...props}`](https://codesandbox.io/s/data-grid-material-ui-forked-l0rie?file=/src/CustomDataGrid.js:2060-2065)

Comment: wow great, it works, thanks a lot @NearHuscarl